# Redirecting from a view to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Can someone help me into this?

I am still new to MVC, now I've a controller named 'A' and called its view.

What I want to happen is that I want to redirect from A's view to another controller for example controller 'B'.

Is that possible to happen?

Please help.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594.aspx) method

MSDN example

```
public ActionResult LogOff() {
    FormsAuth.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

First parameter is the Action name and second is the controller name.